# Problem: The scroll bar appears in the parent window, not next to the "Treeview"

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code, the problem is that the Scrollbar appears in the main window, although its package is not located next to the treeview, I think the solution is a small detail, but I can't get it, can you help me?

```
 def modulo_dashboard(self): 
    self.windows_container = Toplevel()
    self.windows_container.transient(windows_raiz)
    self.windows_container.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.windows_container.resizable(0,0)
    #self.windows_consulta.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_exit) # Invalidar x y    mandar a función con mensaje 
    self.windows_container.geometry("1340x530+2+164")
    #   Medidas del Geometry ("ancho x alto + columna + fila")


    #   Configuración del Treeview
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use("alt") #alt, clam, vista
    style.configure("Treeview", background="skyblue2", foreground="black",
         rowheight=22, fieldbackground="skyblue2", font = ('arial', 11))
    style.map("Treeview", background=[('selected', 'navy')], foreground=[('selected', 'white')])
    #   Agrandar emcabezado
    nametofont("TkHeadingFont").configure(size=12)
```

Here begins the Treeview

```
# Comienza el Treeview
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.windows_container, height = 12, columns = ('#0', '#1'), show="headings")
self.tree.place(x =40, y = 140)

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.windows_container, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

self.tree.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0)
self.tree.column("#1", width=300, minwidth=50)
self.tree.column("#2", width=200, minwidth=50)

self.tree.heading('#0', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Ubicación', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Cantidad Equipos', anchor = CENTER)

self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
self.tree.bind("<Button-1>", self.selusandoclik5)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick the treeview and scrollbar together, better put them in a frame and use `.pack()` on them:

```py
...
# frame for the treeview and scrollbar
frame = Frame(self.windows_container)
frame.place(x=40, y=140)

# Comienza el Treeview
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, height = 12, columns = ('#0', '#1'), show="headings")
self.tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
...
```

Comment: You've beaten me to the punch, it seems! ;)

Comment: You should also add `expand=True` when packing the tree so that the widget expands to fill all extra space in the frame.

Comment: Excellent solution, I already tried it and it worked perfectly, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try `pack`ing the `Scrollbar` before the `Treeview` (declare it first) *-or-* better to use the `before` parameter of `pack()` like so:

```
vsb.pack(side='right', fill='both', before=self.tree)
```

You might also want to set the `fill` to `'y'` so it only fills vertically

Comment: Thank you for helping me, when making the change, it generates this error     _tkinter.TclError: window ".!toplevel2.!treeview" isn't packed

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake - I didn't notice that you were using `place()` for the `Treeview` - you'd have to use `pack()` on it as well in order for this solution to work. Another possible solution is to create a `Frame` (as a child of `self.windows_container`) into which you `pack()` the `Treeview` and `Scrollbar` like I described, then you can `place()` the container `Frame` as you like! *EDIT*: See @acw1668's answer - that's exactly the idea!